# What is sufficient statistics in the context of generalized linear models

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, exponential-family, sufficient-statistics

the three assumptions Andrew Ng makes when deriving GLM are:

> 1. $y\mid x;\theta \sim \operatorname{ExponentialFamily}(\eta)$
> 2. Our goal is to predict the expected value of $T(y)$ given $x$. Since in most of our examples $T(y) = y$, we would like the prediction $h(x)$ to satisfy $h(x)=E[y\mid x]$. (This assumption is satisfied for both logistic regression and linear regression)
> 3. The natural parameter $\eta$ and the inputs $x$ are related linearly: $\eta = \theta^Tx$.

I get assumption 1 and 3. What bothers me is the second assumption. I get that in logistic regression

$$h_\theta(x) = p(y=1\mid x;\theta) = 0 \cdot p(y=0\mid x;\theta) + 1\cdot p(y=1\mid x;\theta) = E[y\mid x;\theta]$$

Hence we want the expected value of $y\mid x;\theta$. (This seems to be a very special case where output is $y\in[1,0]$).
But what exactly is the sufficient statistic in this context and what does the expected value of sufficient statistic represent?

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, a statistic is sufficient with respect to a statistical model and its unknown parameter if no other statistic that can be calculated from the same sample provides additional information as to the value of the parameter. Think of $T(y)$ - the sufficient statistic for the exponential distribution - as containing all the information required to find the value of $\eta$, the parameter for the model, which is our end goal. In other words, the expected value $E[T(y) \vert x]$ contains all the necessary information we want about our input $x$ (to make a prediction on it) from the model.